"Session Google Ads Query" displays no data on Google Analytics
When I go to Acquisition -> Overview -> Google Ads Campaign, I can see the click and impression for each day of the campaign,

but when I want to add the dimension "Session Google Ads Query" (because I want to see the keywords search by the user)

there is no data.

My Google Ads is linked to te GA property (and the name of Ads campaign are displayed, so I guess the Google Ads is correctly linked)
And Auto tagging is enable
Any clue?
Thanks
